# Arrow keys navigation to photo pages with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add arrow key right and left to navigate to photo pages. And each photo page is got navigation section like the one below. Once I press the key, it goes to none stop action forwarding to next page(s). Can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.

```
<div style="margin: 10px auto 0 auto; text-align: center; width: 650px;">
<div class="nav_section" id="navigation">

<ul>

<li> <a href="/photos/view/120"><img src="/photos/square/120-df1dppn7253nge2e929k.jpg"></a> </li>

<li> <a href="/photos/view/118"><img src="/photos/square/118-dmfpm8xtzdg3kb2k85b8.jpg"></a> </li>

<li> <a href="/photos/view/116"><img src="/photos/square/116-kfaga5w36gbhej7g641c.jpg"></a> </li>

... and so on,.... 

</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

and here is rubbish script I have got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        var key = event.which;
        if(key == 37) { // Left arrow key
$('a').trigger('click');
}
if(key == 39) { //Right arrow key
        $('a').trigger('click');
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're clicking every single anchor on the page `$('a')`.  You probably need to change your selector there.

Without more context I can't guide you on what to do -- but you need to figure out the active picture and I assume trigger a click on it (or some navigation element) depending on how your stuff works.

Comment: @XachKaa If you set up an example on http://jsfiddle.net or http://plnkr.co, I'd be happy to help further.

Answer (score 1):

thank you guys,... the problem is solved,... I just add a class to photo links prevP and nextP

and here is the correct script if anyone needs it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        var key = event.which;
        if(key == 37) { // Left arrow key
            $('a.prevP').trigger('click');
        }
        if(key == 39) { //Right arrow key
            $('a.nextP').trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be trouble with your click event for your links. It might be a good idea to just make a function responsible for doing whatever action (back/forward), then call that whenever you need it.